# Express integral as limit of Riemann Sum. Then evaluate.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

I need someone to check my work. I got the wrong answer and I don't know where I went wrong. My answer is $\frac{25}{6}$, but the correct one is $\frac{23}{6}$. My work is below. Hope you can read it.

---

[image: My work.]

Comment: The low contrast in the picture makes it hard to read. Can you improve the picture or type in the text?

Comment: You can find info on [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to typeset math on this site using mathjax/latex.

Comment: All your computations looks fine. The only problem is the initial error in $f(x_i)$ pointed out in the answer below. If you fix this you will get the correct answer.

Comment: Note, $(1 + i/n)^2 = 1 + 2i/n + i^2/n^2$. You have $2i^2/n^2$ for the last term.